# I have one solution with 3 projects, the build order is fine, but dependencies not loading other namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependencies

I have 3 projects in 1 solution file.

- Solution: James

  - Project: James.Domain (class library)
  - Project: James.UnitTests (Test project)
  - Project: James.WebUI (MVC project)

I have ticked the dependencies and the build order seems fine.
When I try to access James.Domain namespace from within a James.WebUI.Controllers namespace, It cannot see the Domain.

Must I do something else to add the dependencies?

**Project: James.Domain

Entities folder**

```
namespace James.Domain.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Username;
        public string Email;
    }
}
```

**Project: James.WebUI

Controllers folder**

```
using James.Domain.Entities; // Errors

namespace James.WebUI.Models
{
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        public DashboardController(repo)
        {

        }

        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

- The Domain project does not depend on anything,
- The UnitTests project relies on both Domain and WebUI
- The WebUI relies on the Domain project

Comment: Have you added your `using` statement to your controller code: `using James.Domain;`

Comment: ah, see OP. yea, .Domain does not appear as an option

Comment: Is this a local build or TFS server?  Have u included a ref to domain project in ur UI project?

Comment: Assuming you did this too, but did you right-click your WebUI project, select "Add Reference", and under the "Solution" tab you can select your Domain project...

Comment: @TroyCarlson - GOT IT, THANKS :D missed out the reference part.. had no idea. CHEERS <man hugs>

Comment: @James Glad you got it.  I added that comment as an answer for others running into similar situations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click on your WebUI project
2. Select "Add Reference"
3. Under the "Solution" tab you can select your Domain project...